# Email In Asp.Net using CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try to send email in asp.net .when admin select checkbox then he/she able to send mail to respective email id and email is also store in database in userss table ..but when i build the code it shows me error

code is

```
protected void chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkAll =
           (CheckBox)Repeateremail.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelectAll");
    if (chkAll.Checked == true)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in Repeateremail.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chkSel =
                     (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkSelect");
            chkSel.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in Repeateremail.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkSelect");
            chkSel.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

in this line

```
CheckBox chkAll =
           (CheckBox)Repeateremail.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelectAll");
```

it show me error in header
error

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' does not contain 
>                a        definition for 'HeaderRow' and no extension method 'HeaderRow' 
>                   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' 
>                could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>                    reference?)

where as in html i use like this in header template

```
<td>
    Check
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged"/>
    Send Mail To All ?                     
</td>
```

and in item template

```
<td>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"/>
</td>
```

Comment: And where is `SendEmailUsingGmail()` defined?

Comment: I think this is copy paste from some site

Comment: you have not posted whole code. please do that.

Comment: yes i use sendemailusingmail()

Comment: I guess the problem is from your tag not the code sending the email. Post your html tag. Somewhere, some tags were not closed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `FindControl()` method, because you are handling the click event for the control you want check property values of anyway, try this instead:

```
protected void chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cast the sender to a CheckBox type
    CheckBox chkAll = sender as CheckBox;

    // The as operator will return null if the cast is not successful,
    // so check for null before we try to use it
    if(chkAll != null)
    {
        if (chkAll.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in Repeateremail.Items)
            {
                CheckBox chkSel =
                 (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkSelect");
                chkSel.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in Repeateremail.Items)
            {
                CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkSelect");
                chkSel.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i add this function which u posted now i face error some thing different

Comment: i done with this but i face error in header...plz see my update question

Comment: Glad this helped you out, feel free to up-vote the answer too. :-)